# Comparing two lists not with same length, finding matches and appending the match with value from first list

Tags: python, list

Consider these two lists with the following values.

List one (has few hundred values):

```
['m99076', 'm10141', 'o87909', 'o90876', 'l17237']
```

List two (has few thousand values):

```
['1', 'foo', '1', 'm10141', 's300']
['2', 'bar', '1', 'u39392', 'n623']
['3', 'fubar', '1', 'o87909', 'z039']
```

Now I have to check both of these arrays and see if some of the indexes match.
Precisely I want to make sure if `list_one[i] == list_two[i][3]`. After I've found that there's a match, I want to tie the value from list_one with `list_two[i][3]`. So the desired output to another list would be (since these two values matched, and the one that remained, didn't):

```
[['foo', 'm10141'], ['fubar', 'o87090']]
```

Been learning programming for a while, but now I'm struggling with this. I know that if I wanted
to compare the values line by line, I'd do this:

```
for i in range(len(...)):
    if list_one[i] == list_two[i][3]:
        values_list.append([list_one[i], list_two[i][3]])
```

But this doesn't apply to my situation, because these values might match anywhere.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below,

```
>>> l1 = ['m99076', 'm10141', 'o87909', 'o90876', 'l17237']
>>> l2 = [['1', 'foo', '1', 'm10141', 's300'],
['2', 'bar', '1', 'u39392', 'n623'],
['3', 'fubar', '1', 'o87909', 'z039']]
>>> l3 = []
>>> for i in l1:
        for j in l2:
            if i == j[3]:
                l3.append([j[1],i])


>>> l3
[['foo', 'm10141'], ['fubar', 'o87909']]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like all you want to do is ensure that the third index of the `list_two` items is *present* in `list_one`. If that's what you want, here's the efficient way to do it:

```
list_one = ['m99076', 'm10141', 'o87909', 'o90876', 'l17237']
list_two = [['1', 'foo', '1', 'm10141', 's300'],
            ['2', 'bar', '1', 'u39392', 'n623'],
            ['3', 'fubar', '1', 'o87909', 'z039']]
set_one = set(list_one)
output = [item for item in list_two if item[3] in set_one]
# [['1', 'foo', '1', 'm10141', 's300'], ['3', 'fubar', '1', 'o87909', 'z039']]
```

If you only want the values as you specified above, just use `(item[1], item[3])` in the beginning of the list comprehension instead of `item`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on list_two, loop implement is applicable.
Below example can be found using the list comprehension.

```
list_one = ['m99076', 'm10141', 'o87909', 'o90876', 'l17237']
list_two = [['1', 'foo', '1', 'm10141', 's300'],
            ['2', 'bar', '1', 'u39392', 'n623'],
            ['3', 'fubar', '1', 'o87909', 'z039']]

values_list = [list(y) for y in [(x[1], x[3]) for x in list_two] if y[1] in list_one]
# [['foo', 'm10141'], ['fubar', 'o87909']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // There are some errors but try something like this, make a two dimensional //array like so, run an if else statement to test array values == or != this should loop through and compare ALL array indexes (:
    public class ArrayComparison {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String list1[] = {"m99076", "m10141", "o87909", "o90876", "l17237"};
            String list2[] = {"1", "foo", "1", "m10141", "s3002", "bar", "1", "u39392", "n6233", "fubar", "1", "o87909", "z039"};


            for(int i = 0; [i] < list1; i++){
                for(int j = 0; [j] < list2; j++){

                }if (list1[i] == list2[j]);
                System.out.println("The values are equal");
            } else
                list1[i] != list2[j];
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you answering a Python question with (1) Java code which (2) you say has errors?